# How can I safely increase the size of a door bolt?

Tags: doors, bolts, doorknob

I live in an apartment right near the garage of the apartment. Every time someone comes in or out of the garage, the change in air pressure causes my door to slam a bit and it sounds like someone is trying to break into my apartment (spoiler alert, they're not).

This bothers me and I haven't found a great way to fix it. I feel like the issue is that the bolt in my door is too small (either that, or the piece of the door that retracts when you turn the knob [I have no idea what it's called] is too small). I'm wondering if you guys had any clever ideas for how I might stop my door from slamming every time the air pressure changes? It's really annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarification, Is this an open door being slammed shut, or a door with clearance when latched that allows it to clatter against the door jamb?

The first can be taken care of with a gas cylinder door closer to retard the closing of the door on the last final bit.

The second can be taken care of by putting thin weatherstrip around the door to stop unwanted airflow, cushion door to door jamb contact and take up the clearance that exists while the door is latched.

I've also used felt pads for reducing the annoyance.

As to whether the bolt is big enough, it's more likely that it's the positioning of the bolt and latch strike plates that's the problem. They can also be moved towards the jamb to take up the slack clearance. It will probably take some finesse with a chisel if they're inlet into the surface along with some filling of the old screw holes so they can be re-drilled for the new strike-plate position. I mention the weatherstrip above because it's the easier of the two fixes and doesn't involve modifications that might be prohibited by your lease.

Comment: It's a door with clearance when latched that allows it to clatter against the door jamb. Solid suggestions all around, I might try the felt pad trick because I have a few of those lying around and I'll see if that works. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Agreed. If you use weatherstripping as the pad, you might also save a bit on heating and cooling (assuming you weatherstrip the whole door frame).

Answer (score 0):

How about a small rubber doorstop that you can kick under the door edge? That'd wedge the door tight without worrying about a modification.

Comment: It's not like that wouldn't work, but that's an extra step I'd have to take every time I walked in the door, and then an extra step every time I want to leave to remove it. I was looking for something more permanent and convenient.

Comment: I would be a little wary of wedging closed an emergency exit like that. If there were a fire it would be easy for you or a guest to forget and be trapped.

Comment: The same could be said of all door chains and door alarms (they make one for  use in hotels that works along the same principle.) e.g. http://www.zapals.com/super-door-stop-alarm-for-personal-security.html?geoip_country=US

Comment: There are two major differences from a door chain: 1) people expect door locking mechanisms to be near the door handle, not on the ground. 2) if the door is wedged closed and you pull hard on it, you may make the door hard to open at all. As for the alarm: I've never seen those but it looks like it's not designed to keep the door closed, just make a noise.

Comment: Yes, their main purpose is noise, but the bottom is typically rubber.. if they were easy to push out of the way, they'd never 'trip' and make noise.